# Uber API compilation errors

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I am installing the Uber API for iOS (Swift). However, I get the following error in the Codeable+Uber.swift file on the below block of code:

> Use of undeclared type 'JSONDecoder'

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    /// JSON Decoder tailored to the Uber API JSON
    public static var uberDecoder: JSONDecoder {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        return decoder
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Xcode and Swift are you using? You need at least Xcode 9.0.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, I'm running v8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSONDecoder` was added in Swift 4 / Xcode 9.0. You are getting the error because you are using Swift 3 / Xcode 8

All apps must use Xcode 9 with a Base SDK of iOS 11 starting in July.

It's best to keep up-to-date at all times.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no `import Foundation`. Just add `import Foundation` to top of file.

**Updated code:**

```
import Foundation

extension JSONDecoder {
    /// JSON Decoder tailored to the Uber API JSON
    public static var uberDecoder: JSONDecoder {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        return decoder
    }
}
```

Or maybe you are using Swift 3 or lower. Then you need to update Xcode.